# Munge my password

Tags: code-golf

Common words should still be avoided to be used as passwords. This challenge is about coding a very simple program that munges a given password (**M**odify **U**ntil **N**ot **G**uessed **E**asily).

**Input**

A word, which is a string written in the alphabet `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`. It does not matter if the letters are lowercase or uppercase.

**Munging**

1. Change any repeated sequence of a same **letter** to itself preceded by the number of times the letter was repeated (`LLLL` with `4L`)
2. Change the first `a` with `@`
3. Change the first `b` with `8`
4. Change the first `c` with `(`
5. Change the first `d` with `6`
6. Change the first `e` with `3`
7. Change the first `f` with `#`
8. Change the first `g` with `9`
9. Change the first `h` with `#`
10. Change the first `i` with `1`
11. Change the second `i` with `!`
12. Change the first `k` with `<`
13. Change the first `l` with `1`
14. Change the second `l` with `i`
15. Change the first `o` with `0`
16. Change the first `q` with `9`
17. Change the first `s` with `5`
18. Change the second `s` with `$`
19. Change the first `t` with `+`
20. Change the first `v` with `>`
21. Change the second `v` with `<`
22. Change the first `w` with `uu`
23. Change the second `w` with `2u`
24. Change the first `x` with `%`
25. Change the first `y` with `?`

Rule 1 must be applied the needed number of times until it is not possible to apply it more. After that the rest of the rules are applied.

**Output** The munged word

**Examples**

- `codegolf`    --> `(0639o1#`
- `programming` --> `pr09r@2m1ng`
- `puzzles`     --> `pu2z135`
- `passwords`   --> `p@25uu0r6$`
- `wwww`        --> `4uu`
- `aaaaaaaaaaa` --> `11a`
- `lllolllolll` --> `3103io3l`
- `jjjmjjjj` --> `3jm4j`

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so please make your program as short as possible!

Nothing in this post should be used as password ideas or as any part of password practices.

Comment: The very fact that programs like this are possible means that the attacker could write them and munge the password (and try the various munges) just as easily (even easier because they often have access to better hardware). So just for safety's sake I will say: **nothing** in this post should be used as password ideas or as any part of password practices.

Comment: I recommend making that disclaimer bold and duplicating it at the top. You can never be too careful...

Answer (score 11):

## Java 8, <s>237</s> <s>321</s> <s>319</s> <s>280</s> <s>247</s> <s>241</s> <s>240</s> 237 bytes

```java
s->{for(int a[]=new int[26],i=0,l=s.length,t,x;i<l;i+=t){for(t=0;++t+i<l&&s[i]==s[t+i];);System.out.print((t>1?t+"":"")+(++a[x=s[i]-65]>2?s[i]:"@8(63#9#1J<1MN0P9R5+U>u%?ZABCDEFGH!JKiMNOPQR$TU<2XYZ".charAt(x+26*~-a[x])+(x==22?"u":"")));}}
```

+84 bytes because the rules got changes.. (*EDIT: Finally back to my initial 237 bytes.*) Replacing `WWWW` with `222W` is easy in Java, but with `4W` not.. If only Java had a way to use the regex capture-group for something.. Getting the length with `"$1".length()`, replacing the match itself with `"$1".replace(...)`, converting the match to an integer with `new Integer("$1")`, or using something similar as Retina (i.e. `s.replaceAll("(?=(.)\\1)(\\1)+","$#2$1")`) or JavaScript (i.e. `s.replaceAll("(.)\\1+",m->m.length()+m.charAt(0))`) would be my number 1 thing I'd like to see in Java in the future to benefit codegolfing.. >.> I think this is the 10th+ time I hate Java can't do anything with the capture-group match..
-78 bytes thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire*.

I/O is uppercase.

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##nZBdT8IwFIbv/RW1fqSzsMAMRBkFERA/9oGbRGXZRZ0Tq3Mja1GImX8du8GV8WptT9Jzmuc9Pe8b/aTVZB7Gb8/v6yCinAOTsvh7BwAWizB9oUEIrDwF4DNhzyBAwStNPR9wRZfVTIY8XFDBAmCBGBCw5tXO90uSIqkAqOeTOPzK1Tyt6VcYqVUiwtUojGfitSIqS521I51hIpQCEqSmYyywrB4eco/5hHBPpr6u6O6Ki/BDTRZCnadSESHRqXcFhrAFoYIRxtRbkhyqNht@R@vm1xY8O0HN473Tvfp1u25atfGp08CTzuKgO@2d9wfDi9Hl7vUNMy17fOvs303a2sPjFKr5nD2BllhrHv1UpbAvOywJ0bQuXBQNFUXPsrW@sWC@eIqkBVsnCq8@pJPIFfKnM2kYVTY2xmqAYN8eDEe2cQFVkfTzRmlKV0gpPAXg75xRjLYvBTx27JHTM80ra1SOn0ynxtAtx/Zc9952BuXoe7lKgYZh2Nso19iW@z8y28nWvw)

```java
s->{                           // Method with String parameter and no return-type
  for(int a[]=new int[26],     //  Array with 26x 0
          i=0,                 //  Index-integer, starting at 0
          l=s.length,          //  Length
          t,x;                 //  Temp integers
      i<l;                     //  Loop (1) over the characters of the input
      i+=t){                   //    After every iteration: Increase `i` by `t`
    for(t=0;++                 //   Reset `t` to 1
        t+i<l                  //   Inner loop (2) from `t+i` to `l` (exclusive)
        &&s[i]==s[t+i];        //   as long as the `i`'th and `t+i`'th characters are equal
    );                         //   End of inner loop (2)
    System.out.print(          //   Print:
     (t>1?t+"":"")             //    If `t` is larger than 1: print `t`
     +(++a[x=s[i]-65]>2?       //    +If the current character occurs for the third time:
       s[i]                    //      Simply print the character
      :                        //     Else:
       "@8(63#9#1J<1MN0P9R5+U>u%?ZABCDEFGH!JKiMNOPQR$TU<2XYZ".charAt(x
                               //      Print the converted character at position `x`
        +26*~-a[x])            //       + 26 if it's the second time occurring
       +(x==22?"u":"")));      //      And also print an additional "u" if it's 'W'
  }                            //  End of loop (1)
}                              // End of method
```

Answer (score 10):

## JavaScript (ES6), 147 bytes

```js
s=>[[/(.)\1+/g,m=>m.length+m[0]],..."a@b8c(d6e3f#g9h#i1k<l1o0q9s5t+v>x%y?i!lis$v<".match(/../g),["w","uu"],["w","2u"]].map(r=>s=s.replace(...r))&&s
```

### Test Cases

```js
f=
s=>[[/(.)\1+/g,m=>m.length+m[0]],..."a@b8c(d6e3f#g9h#i1k<l1o0q9s5t+v>x%y?i!lis$v<".match(/../g),["w","uu"],["w","2u"]].map(r=>s=s.replace(...r))&&s

;["codegolf","programming","puzzles","passwords","aabaa","www","lllolllolll","jmnpruz"]
.forEach(t=>console.log(t,"->",f(t)))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100%!important}
```

### Explanation

Runs through a series of replacements on the input string, `s`, in the order specified by the challenge. Each item in the series is an array or string, with two items, that is then spread (`...r`) and passed to `s.replace()`.

```js
s=>[
    [/(.)\1+/g, m=>m.length + m[0]],// first replacement: transform repeated letters
                                    // into run-length encoding

                                    // string split into length-2 partitions and
                                    // spread into the main array
    ..."a@b8c(d6e3f#g9h#i1k<l1o0q9s5t+v>x%y?i!lis$v<".match(/../g),
                                    // next replacements: all single-char replacements.
                                    // "second" versions are placed at the end so they
                                    //    replace the second instance of that char

    ["w","uu"],["w","2u"]           // last replacements: the two "w" replacements
]
.map(r=> s = s.replace(...r))       // run all replacements, updating s as we go
&& s                                // and return the final string
```

Comment: Very good answer

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 69 bytes

-9 bytes thanks to Emigna

```
γvygD≠×yÙ}J.•k®zĀÒĀ+ÎÍ=ëµι
•"@8(63#9#1<1095+>%?!i$<"ø'w„uu„2u‚â«vy`.;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//3OayynSXR50LDk@vPDyz1kvvUcOi7EPrqo40HJ50pEH7cN/hXtvDqw9tPbeTCyij5GChYWasbKlsaGNoYGmqbadqr5ipYqN0eId6@aOGeaWlQMIISMw6vOjQ6rLKBD3r//8LEouLy/OLUooB)

Comment: You could use `'w„uu„2u‚â`

Comment: Plz could you verify result for wwww as input?

Comment: @mdahmoune It outputs `4uu`

Comment: @Emigna Cartesian product, good idea.

Comment: First part can be `γvygD≠×yÙ}J`

Comment: You also don't need `€S`

Comment: @Emigna Yeah, it was left in from something I had before

Comment: Thanx for the update ;)

Answer (score 6):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 152 + 1 (`-p`) = 153 bytes

```perl
s/(.)\1+/(length$&).$1/ge;%k='a@b8c(d6e3f#g9h#i1j!k<l1mio0q9r5s$t+u>v<x%y?'=~/./g;for$i(sort keys%k){$r=$k{$i};$i=~y/jmru/ilsv/;s/$i/$r/}s/w/uu/;s/w/2u/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FchBDoIwEADAr2hYBGJkRYPRAOpDvKAUKEWLXQoSAk@3xjlOw1QdGkPo@t4tWKNbs1fRlrDyfAiwYJEtEie93o8PNzuwfW4Vp9LiQbUUcR08udy@TyokaNf63MUfe7g4yYw@FlEuFXCXpGoXgg1kC28ElYAYgU8R8GQesHoqjbymDiNC4AgKJ8Ietf5HjzuNxjQpUS9VRl/ZtFy@yGyaHw)

Comment: Plz what do you mean by (-p)?

Comment: @mdahmoune `-p` is used as an argument to `perl` at the commandline that automatically reads input from `STDIN` and `print`s the contents of `$_` at the end of the script. TIO allows that option, and since `perl -pe<code>` is 1 more byte than `perl -e<code>` it's counted as one additional byte.

Comment: I think you've made a typo, shouldn't the `~` between `j~k` be an `!` instead? Currently it replaced the second occurrence of `i` with a `~` instead of a `!`.

Comment: @Xcali #testingonproduction

Comment: @NieDzejkob There's no better place.  That's the only way you know it will work in production.

Answer (score 4):

Probably not the most golfed it could be, but it works.

-6 bytes thanks to ovs

-77 Bytes thanks to  NieDzejkob and Jonathan French

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>329</strike> <strike>323 bytes</strike> 246 bytes

```python
import re;n=input()
for a in re.finditer('(\w)\\1+',n):b=a.group();n=n.replace(b,str(len(b))+b[0],1)
for A,B,C in[('abcdefghikloqstvxyw','@8(63#9#1<1095+>%?','uu'),('ilsvw','!i$<','2u')]:
	for a,b in zip(A,list(B)+[C]):n=n.replace(a,b,1)
print(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7RTsJAEEWf5Stq0OxMummoRCMVVOAz2j50YQtTl@m63YL483WrLz5MJjm59@bYqz@2PB8GOtnW@cjpF14R294DTurWRVVEHGhSE@/JawcCigsWRRoLyZipVZUcXNtbwFDkxGlrqp0GJTvvwGgGhRirfFbK9G9wLTdyG0ZzEJXa7XV9ONKHaT87f/66XoQU78/wNJ8upukynS0e49f7twD7XqAEQaY7j5lbuluG9xBomU1ufkWlGlW/ycJaGuo8bDDOtyVm/71CahSxjtgD4zA0TXMK1/wA)

Comment: I think you may drop `.lower()`

Comment: That makes sense, I wasn't sure whether I needed to handle uppercase or not.

Comment: [321 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY7NboMwAIPP5Sk8ukqJQKhQbVqhdHuHHtsewl@bjSVZEgo8PQvTDhxt2Z@tRnuXYjdN/FtJbaHr7JQbqyOjWm6zIT8Rn32geENJUL2i3qFZ47bHfQ0e4@uANobc4mcP8wIb4HFE33UYNhjffZqNM4A/oeUwz3gc0Ceds0XOheosoV4jNRi4cMtRw0XFba2J9smlp5c48ENB0yJn0U3LTpG5KCJdq5aVNSlCd5S0tSAFpUFx3l4XuDH1VmXOnJkV7oMIS@qtePMfPyY0FflcCUrXjK8BO8epE9Gn5C5wTtIlbEiXuzM0/MuHMfWU5sISQadJMWN6qSvzCw).

Comment: [320 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY9Bc4IwEIXP8itesZ1JhgwjOu1UkLb/waN6CAialm7SJIj8ehrbi8d9u997b83oz5pW06S@jbYetim2pfM2daZTvriKUVC5ZbH8QPWKmuH4gmaFdo7TGuc5VIavDboMeoGfNdwzfILLG4a@x/UJ43vMRcDVAzoF94jLBsOyD6Ii03vGo1ZbSCgKyWmr6Kh8Y1nM9gPf77MkFsTzqpTpyereMF5QSaltTCfrhlUiFGVdQ6ziPKl2i8Od3ZhHs7qUQSyq8ACJmkcz1SbLzT@QU3kjkjqA2SGRuywPQ/qpVdjulvm91zW/j715ir97kfHIWEWeEZ8mI50btD26Xw).

Comment: Actually, your answer doesn't work. `jjjmjjjj` should output `3jm4j` but outputs `3jm3jj`. Edit: [258 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY7RToNAEEWf5Ssw1exM2JBio7FYVNrPAB6WdqGL22FdltZ@PS76oA83k5xM7j3m6o49raZJnUxvXWhlQJkiMzrAoOltKEJFnsaNooNy0gKD8oJlmUSME6Z1JuLW9qMBfKGMYiuNFnsJNR@cBS0JasSoLpYVT34Lc77lu7m0ACbq/UE27VF96P5zcOev64Vx9v4MT6vFepFskuX6MXq9f/NwHBlyYEoP5/nnVt1t/HnwtEqDmz9TQa382c0R0/9GeSEqDloNDrYYFbsKZ@CljFXkgHCauq47@XTf) with this problem fixed

Comment: @NieDzejkob [255 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY5RT8IwEICf5VfMoOld1ixMopEJKvAztj200EHrdqtdC/LrZ8EXHy6XfLn78tmLP/Y0H0fd2d75xKk3WmmywQNOmt4lItEUadZo2muvHDCozlhVeco4YSFXIju4PljA@EiZU7YVOwWSD95BqwgkYirLWc3zP@Gab/g2SktgQu72qjkc9Vfbfw/@9HM5M84@X@FlPl1M82U@Wzyn748fEYbAkAPT7XC63tzrh2VcT5HWxeTu6jX8lqoodMoJr2CNxf8iwaHVg4cNpuW2xtLciqzT5IFwHI0xXRzzCw).

Comment: @JonathanFrech [246 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY7RTsJAEEWf5Stq0OxMummoRCMVVOAz2j50YQtTl@m63YL483WrLz5MJjm59@bYqz@2PB8GOtnW@cjpF14R294DTurWRVVEHGhSE@/JawcCigsWRRoLyZipVZUcXNtbwFDkxGlrqp0GJTvvwGgGhRirfFbK9G9wLTdyG0ZzEJXa7XV9ONKHaT87f/66XoQU78/wNJ8upukynS0e49f7twD7XqAEQaY7j5lbuluG9xBomU1ufkWlGlW/ycJaGuo8bDDOtyVm/71CahSxjtgD4zA0TXMK1/wA) except the Python 2 starts getting really similar and I posted a link there with it ported to Python 3 for 192 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>166</s> 124 bytes

```
(.)\1+
$.&$1
([a-y])(?<!\1.+)
¶$&
¶w
uu
T`l¶`@8(63#9#1j<\1mn0\p9r5+u>\w%?_`¶.
([ilsvw])(?<!\1.+)
¶$&
¶w
2u
T`i\lsv¶`!i$<_`¶.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bczBDoIgAMbxO2/hRIdzsajVcnPZrRfoFi1cmqOhMIhYPpgP4IsRde7yXf77frp98qH2CToyj3BGSQ4gTiEB6Fwv3pcMVWVECc4zME8wDeOAteDExDyxww5t13ERk0dJST8sqSr0Jrd76pLqyuYJB4QL83J/mdWX4TT0QEUclr@L9zfZtJ0Ud6C07HTd93zogLLjKFoDVG2Mk7oxHw) Explanation:

```
(.)\1+
$.&$1
```

Replace a run of repeated letters with the length and the letter.

```
([a-y])(?<!\1.+)
¶$&
```

Match the first occurrence of the letters `a` to `y` and mark them with a placeholder.

```
¶w
uu
```

Fix the first occurrence of `w`.

```
T`l¶`@8(63#9#1j<\1mn0\p9r5+u>\w%?_`¶.
```

Fix the first occurrence of all the other letters from `a` to `y` and delete the placeholders.

```
([ilsvw])(?<!\1.+)
¶$&
```

Mark the (originally) second occurrence of the letters `i`, `l`, `s`, `v`, or `w` with a placeholder.

```
¶w
2u
```

Fix the second occurrence of `w`.

```
T`i\lsv¶`!i$<_`¶.
```

Fix the second occurrence of the other four letters.

Comment: Do you think it’s possible to golf it further?

Comment: @mdahmoune Yes, I think I can save 33 bytes.

Comment: I up-voted your answer :) 
it will be great if your save the 33 bytes ;)

Comment: @mdahmoune Good news, I actually saved 42 bytes!

Comment: Great, your code is the second shortest ;)

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>221</s> <s>218</s> 213 bytes

```hs
($(f<$>words"w2u li i! s$ v< a@ b8 c( d6 e3 f# g9 h# i1 k< l1 o0 q9 s5 t+ v> wuu x% y?")++[r]).foldr($)
f(a:b)(h:t)|a==h=b++t|1>0=h:f(a:b)t
f _ s=s
r(a:b)|(p,q)<-span(==a)b=[c|c<-show$1+length p,p>[]]++a:r q
r s=s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LZDNTsMwEITveYohDZItt6gBgWgUBx4AThzTqnL@ozqxaycNVHl2Qtqy0uzOtyPtYSthD7mUU8O3E/FIEXrRoExm3eGxh6xR38F6OIUQ70hekRJkL8ifUCxQblAtUPs4hJA@1BrHDewzOoZThKHv8X2PnzeXMhabHX0olMwM8ahTEBEklFRBR0fBecUTxrrRj9a8Cm5Z5xTYw3LrmCuPRC@PNFxZLVrCuaAJj9MxnReVGjyfybwtuwp6qaN4t2NMBAZHx1wuTI2oW3A0Qn/uQbZiFem@@@rMRwsPAozBBY/mNrsGgiJ2U5XlpZKFu4SrjSqNaJq6La/Yn88yt1crrL39aoZhrsuUUqp/ubvpNy2kKO20SrX@Aw)

Abuses `foldr` to run the string through a sequence of string transformations backwards. The  sequence "starts" with `r` which does the repetition count replacement by using `span` to break the tail of the string when it stops being equal to the head. If the first part of that is non-empty it's a repetition so we print the length +1. Next we curry an argument into `f` for each character replacement in (reverse) order. The replacements are encoded as a single string with the first character being the character to be replaced and the rest as the string (since the w replacements are multiple characters) to go in its place. I put these encoded strings in one big string separated by spaces so that `words` can break it into a list for me.

EDIT: Thanks @Laikoni for saving me 5 bytes! That was a clever use of `$` I didn't think of. I also didn't know that `<-` trick.

Comment: Thanx for detailed explanation ;)

Comment: You can use `(p,q)<-span(==a)b` instead of `let(p,q)=span(==a)b` and `p>[]`  instead of `p/=[]`.

Comment: Save two more bytes by making `m` pointfree: `($(f<$>words"w2u ... y?")++[r]).foldr($)` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LZDNTsMwEITveYohDZItt6gBgWgUBx4AThzTqnL@ozqxaycNVHl2Qtqy0uzOtyPtYSthD7mUU8O3E/FIEXrRoExm3eGxh6xR38F6OIUQ70hekRJkL8ifUCxQblAtUPs4hJA@1BrHDewzOoZThKHv8X2PnzeXMhabHX0olMwM8ahTEBEklFRBR0fBecUTxrrRj9a8Cm5Z5xTYw3LrmCuPRC@PNFxZLVrCuaAJj9MxnReVGjyfybwtuwp6qaN4t2NMBAZHx1wuTI2oW3A0Qn/uQbZiFem@@@rMRwsPAozBBY/mNrsGgiJ2U5XlpZKFu4SrjSqNaJq6La/Yn88yt1crrL39aoZhrsuUUqp/ubvpNy2kKO20SrX@Aw "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>224</s> 219 bytes

```r
function(s,K=function(x)el(strsplit(x,"")),u=rle(K(s)))
Reduce(function(x,y)sub(K('abcdefghiiklloqsstvvwwxy')[y],c(K('@8(63#9#1!<1i095$+><'),'uu','2u',K('%?'))[y],x),1:24,paste0(gsub("1","",paste(u$l)),u$v,collapse=""))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU5NT8MwDL3vV0A3lFgEaR0fYqgF7rtxRTukadpFuE2Jm37sz5cEEFiy/Wy/Jz@3oCmcdDNvdH@yJcGqushulsq3qje25SQO@d8wgUZOvaMOTc8nkSQAwucONT9wAoDVmy690vxfIWYgX4Qzk4UqdVWfjPlAtJ9E/TCM4zQzeJ@PQkXK6yN/uF3v1@lllprt/n5z/ZwxEMx7JtgulMC5emHwrZhApE@7O9FJ6vWW1/FNkibB1M@K@w1Ge5tBKIsoO9J5NLyQ7DqcueKJsqWuLVZB1DlbO9k0pq3j5M9n1BSRJBqtKyMeQ4SGwf5vJiAqWL4A)

Nasty, but the main part is the iterative substitution in the `Reduce`. `sub` changes only the first occurrence of the match.

*Thanks to JayCe for pointing out a nice golf!*

Comment: Good job :)))))

Comment: [save 1 byte by rearranging args.](https://tio.run/##RU7LTsMwELz3KyAN8loYqSkPUZQA99y4Ig6u46QW2zh44zz688GuEF1pd2dWM9pxC5q9k26Go@4PtiK@qq/yu6X2reqNbYFEWfyTiWsE6h11aHqYRJJwLnzhUEMJFPBQdJJ6vYGG/B6SLAkScT6BTzGK00Eoiyg70kW0rz505ZWGyw8x82gugcm9qnTdHIz5RrQ/RP0wjOM0M/45fwkVJe/P8HS/3q2z6zwzm91jevuaMy6Y90ywbRhBc/PG@NkxcZG9bB/EwBeSXYczKEiUrXRjsQ5RO2cbJ49H0zaR@dMJNUUkiUbrqojHUGFhCPTXCRc1X34B) Doesn't make a huge difference I know ;)

Comment: @JayCe I found some more bytes :-)

Answer (score 2):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 173 bytes

```lua
s=...for c,r in("uua@b8c(d6e3f#g9h#i1i!jjk<l1limmnno0ppq9rrs5s$t+v>v<wuuw2ux%y?zz"):gmatch"(.)(.u?)"do s=s:gsub(c..c.."+",function(p)return#p..c end):gsub(c,r,1)end print(s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYpbDoIwEACvUosmbSSNaDRqRLwKlodVaOtuF5TLVz5M5mcy01EZI@ZKqcYB0ykwYwUnKm/3oxbVod41SXt6JCYzi@fzdemyzvS9tW7j/fsEgHtchvVwHS4j0bilz@pbTBOX57Yvg35woaRQVEheOYY5nluku9BKzfA1TxuyOhhnhZdQBwKb@Lmx2lbyv6aQZnJ25sHYIFDGGH2JODqo8Ac)

Ungolfed and explained:

```lua
s = ...


--This string contains every character to replace, followed by
--the character(s) it should be replaced with.
--
--It also contains all characters for which repeated sequences
--of them should be replaced by "<number><character>". That is,
--all letters in the alphabet. This way, a single loop can do
--both the "replace repeated characters" and "encode characters"
--operations, saving a for loop iterating over the alphabet.
--
--Characters that shouldn't be replaced will be replaced with
--themselves.
--
--In order to avoid matching half of the "replace u with u"
--command as the replace part of another command, "uu" is placed
--at the beginning of the string. This ensures that only the
--2-character replacements for "w" get an extra "u".

cmdstring = "uua@b8c(d6e3f#g9h#i1i!jjk<l1limmnno0ppq9rrs5s$t+v>v<wuuw2ux%y?zz"


--Iterate over all the search/replace commands.
--The character to replace is in the "c" variable, the string to
--replace it with is in "r".
--
--Due to the dummy search/replace commands (i.e. "mm") placed
--in the string, this loop will also iterate over all letters
--of the alphabet.

for c,r in cmdstring:gmatch("(.)(.u?)") do
	
	--First, replace any occurences of the current letter
	--multiple times in a row with "<number><letter>".
	s = s:gsub(c..c.."+", function(p)
		return #p .. c
	end)
	
	--Then, replace the first occurence of the letter
	--with the replacement from the command string.
	s = s:gsub(c, r, 1)
end

print(s)
```

Comment: Lol lua :) good job

Answer (score 2):

## **C# (.NET Core), <s>317</s>, <s>289</s>, 279 Bytes**

```
p=>{string r="",l=r,h=r,c="a@b8c(d6e3f#g9h#i1i!k<l1lio0q9s5s$t+v>v<wuw2x%y?";int i=0,n=p.Length,d,a=1;for(;i<n;i++){h=p[i]+"";if(h==p[(i==n-1?i:i+1)]+""&&i!=n-1)a++;else{d=c.IndexOf(h);if(d>=0&&d%2<1){l=c[d+1]+"";h=l=="u"?"uu":l;c=c.Remove(d,2);}r+=a>1?a+""+h:h;a=1;}}return r;};
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##ZVFdixMxFH22vyKbdcuEzJZORXGbyVRZWBBWFBV8KH2ISToJpklNMu12h/ntNTOtVvBCPu7NObmHc3m45c7LI0jBDQsBfPau9mwz6ivtsPcRIouag53TAnxk2mYhem3r5QowXwf0F3dhXJhnYJQhBkBBCyB3QtbOrGEO4PbUb5NAQ9o8PxsZhmuSs3deDMk@RX8aY9x5QdCR/9p9PYQoN5OHxvKSK@aXq/wsoQK8Tu2PW1q1pwrwFMLcUJ@rtDiF7N2PtzwTb@Sr9XV9p651oa9@lqYw2k1/3YXX4WXEu2pX7pv97OnmsIBE2wg0neaWbieP0tZR5SJntCBr5zOiS0s0xqhVdLvUKwwTYZ0pmrJMU2pvi4Wea1yg/mk81ld9CTGMiTRBtoLyyQcr5NOnREI9VVR0Oh6Lm1lZoNZQvhS4GL5V1FAKG7iATQPnhvBE/SI3biczkc8Q6TymrCoWLIGxmivSa@w6L2PjLfCkI8fRi399TPol4wqcB508BNqeZoj@mHzvbHBGTr57HeWjtjLjdcJPvrn75Px779khQwhdhtSNuuNv)

I hope it's ok to receive a char array as an input and not a string.

**Ungolfed**:

```
string result = "", casesCharReplacement = result, currentChar = result, cases = "a@b8c(d6e3f#g9h#i1i!k<l1lio0q9s5s$t+v>v<wuw2x%y?";
int i = 0, n = pas.Length, casesIndex, charAmounts = 1;

// For every char in the pass.
for (; i < n; i++)
{
    currentChar = pas[i] + "";
    // if the next char is equal to the current and its not the end of the string then add a +1 to the repeated letter.
    if (currentChar == (pas[(i == n - 1 ? i : i + 1)] + "") && i != n - 1)
        charAmounts++;
    else
    {
        // Finished reading repeated chars (N+Char).
        casesIndex = cases.IndexOf(currentChar);
        // Look for the replacement character: only if the index is an even position, otherwise I could mess up with letters like 'i'.
        if (casesIndex >= 0 && casesIndex % 2 < 1)
        {
            casesCharReplacement = cases[casesIndex + 1]+"";
            // Add the **** +u
            currentChar = casesCharReplacement == "u"?"uu": casesCharReplacement;
            // Remove the 2 replacement characters (ex: a@) as I won't need them anymore.
            cases = cases.Remove(casesIndex, 2);
        }
        // if the amount of letters founded is =1 then only the letter, otherwise number and the letter already replaced with the cases.
        result += charAmounts > 1 ? charAmounts + ""+currentChar : currentChar;
        charAmounts = 1;
    }
}
return result;
```

Comment: Yes it’s ok :) for the input

Answer (score 2):

### C++, <s>571</s> <s>495</s> <s>478</s> 444 bytes

-127 bytes thanks to Zacharý

```cpp
#include<string>
#define F r.find(
#define U(S,n)p=F s(S)+b[i]);if(p-size_t(-1)){b.replace(i,1,r.substr(p+n+1,F'/',n+p)-p-2));r.replace(p+1,F'/',p+1)-p,"");}
#define V(A)i<A.size();++i,c
using s=std::string;s m(s a){s b,r="/a@/b8/c(/d6/e3/f#/g9/h#/i1//i!/k</l1//li/o0/q9/s5//s$/t+/v>/wuu//w2u/x%/y?/";int c=1,i=0;for(;V(a)=1){for(;a[i]==a[i+1]&&1+V(a)++);b+=(c-1?std::to_string(c):"")+a[i];}for(i=0;V(b)){auto U("/",1)else{U("//",2)}}return b;}
```

the `"/a@/b8/c(/d6/e3/f#/g9/h#/i1//i!/k</l1//li/o0/q9/s5//s$/t+/v>/wuu//w2u/x%/y?/"` string is used to transform from one character to others. 1 `/` means that the first "next char" should be replaced by what follow the next `/`, 2 means that the second "next char" should be replaced by what follows.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##VVLLbtswEDxbX8HQbUxCsmnaTVBbkpMcmh8ImksbBJREu0QpUeWjbm3o29OVEhspARG7Ozuzy4HKtp3uyvJlrJpSh0qiTBnnrRT15lzLoKCa3SYaV3KrGonukZ1BUJFz5St5SBra5vfIkQcaF9/UE03VlrRTpw7y2ZMpp/RYzKxstSglUQlP7MyFAqRJGzcxT@4nbJI0cUun7XRBaWrPze0JhQDQBGOadufRj@SOquxu1g8iNI1jlZRRcLAwcrnz1Xr9un7qUE0cEvToUJHYHDNxy4rPrCSsumZyybZjtluxH2OmOGPqgv3MmIZIK2bm7NeKuSvG3AfmY/Z7w/YhMLZfBPbnI/t7w3CqGo/KnCcqn6dbY0n6SATNOT0OiQBD8hzumD9dXvK4B@OYpkWck3LKb4Y9vXl@XZWUdA2PjHtW2vUCveojKcBDEbwBuzHDCadSO3nsE8gWtOus9ME2qEi7lyjqN6qFaghFx2g0TFCN8kpocMo@a@V8NlRboWz2zqnkXbzZII3yXmB0xKWp5M7oLU4wmV8vV4aPcZcMUGvNzoq6BgqgrZ2v7O2i5pCdGsLhoKXrwbA48OXVGRDO7Y2tBuh2cRXC3F5/OKF7OAB8CuFU0Vqbtw@AJZ8vlVlq3EWjLo1GYBYipWmcR71Tl0igNdKDA6PBOg@vqYmA/9c6T4ExUltEPLrIkZg5CdSKQvHVr9IEj7IM4S/WgnAlvSy9rFA/ZY1wz/6v7012oMAc3AdDNvneTKC7i7qXfw)

Comment: Great, could you please add a tio.run link ?

Comment: @mdahmoune TIO link is added, with the code to test for your test cases :)

Comment: [494 bytes](https://pastebin.com/Pbr11YBY), and update the TIO link accordingly if you change it.

Comment: @Zacharý You need to put a space between the macro name and the macro content, otherwise, it throws an error when compiling with C++ 17. Also, do you know how to delete a TIO link ? ( since the old one is useless )

Comment: You can't delete a TiO link. But you can remove the reference to it in your answer.

Comment: [479 bytes](https://pastebin.com/zpqw7XvD), and if you update the post, update the TIO link accordingly.

Comment: Replace `p!=size_t(-1)` with `p-size_t(-1)` to save one byte (ofc update the TIO link afterwards)

Comment: Somehow ... there's more left: [474 bytes](https://pastebin.com/1LBk2gPc)

Comment: [446 bytes](https://pastebin.com/w5GF77Uh)

Comment: [444 bytes](https://pastebin.com/20KAedXU)

Answer (score 1):

### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 123 bytes

**122 bytes code + 1 for `-p`.**

Developed independently from @[Xcali](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/72767/xcali)'s [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145781/9365), but using a very similar process.

```perl
s/(.)\1+/$&=~y!!!c.$1/ge;eval"s/$1/$2/"while'a@b8c(d6e3f#g9h#i1i!k<l1lio0q9s5t+v>v<x%y?'=~/(.)(.)/g;s/s/\$/;s/w/uu/;s;w;2u
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYxLDoIwFAD33IKPgiHyBIORAOpB2CCU0lho5fERFhzdiskkk9mMJB0PlUJwvEPmu2Dt03XWdb3wLB8oicmYcwNhCysAY6oZJ3b@eF4Lp7yQc2XSqDaZz/RXwn3OxOkdYdi7421MPrv5bqfrf7wBNEZAyCzYPMEwbI6nOBiUKkRJqOCVJjtBu7xpWEs1OSwLJ6jJHHESXYlfIXsmWlRH@QM)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>220</s> <s>216</s> <s>194</s> <s>190</s> 188 bytes

```python
import re
S=re.sub(r'(.)\1+',lambda m:`len(m.group(0))`+m.group(1),input())
for a,b in zip('abcdefghiiklloqsstvvxyww',list('@8(63#9#1!<1i095$+><%?')+['uu','2u']):S=S.replace(a,b,1)
print S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NczBTgIxEIDh@z5FDZCZyTYbitEIAfQd9qgmdKHAxG5buy0FX37loIf/8F@@cEtn7xbjyH3wMYloqnYTTTPkDiNgQx@qBml13x206Fc7axz2zSn6HHBOtKv/R5FkF3JCouroo9CyE@zEDwcE3e0P5ng6M39Z67@HIV0u11spd5iHhPD2gs@Pk@VEPawVz5dP03q7nr0C1e@QM0hYZPikVbtpm2iC1XuDd10qqkJkl0Q7jlBK8X/BLw)

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 187 bytes

```python
import re
S=re.sub(r'(.)\1+',lambda m:str(len(m.group(0)))+m.group(1),input())
for a,b in zip('abcdefghiiklloqsstvvxyww',[*'@8(63#9#1!<1i095$+><%?','uu','2u']):S=S.replace(a,b,1)
print(S)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYxLbsIwFADXzSlcQeX3iBXholaA@N0hy9KFAwasOrZ5sTFw@cCiLGak2Uy4xZN3k743bfAUGemiXpKuutQAcahwK0surGqbvWLtvIsEVjtoqyP5FGCMiOUrJArjQoqAWBw8MSUaZhy7mwBcNbu9PhxPxvxZ689dFy@X6y1nLn5GfDOF78lgNpDvC2nGs69huVp8rLngKT31mfgvzutlXZEOVu00PMdCYhHIuAg19n3O2f/z9gA)

Comment: Thanx Tfeld 192 bytes https://tio.run/##NY3NisIwFEb3fYoMjtx7aShGUUbx7x26HAVTjRomTTJpYtWX7xR0FgfO4Vt8/hGvzo67TtfehciCyspVUEWTKgyABe1EDtzIujpJVi8ORlmsi0twyeOI6JD/hyCurU8RibKzC0zyimnLntojyOp4UufLVesfY9xv08Tb7f4ADtsvnE0G84H4WAo9mk8/8/VyuAHKvxHafk8JiL903Ot@Ua7KIihv5FFh/8AFZT5oG1nZddC2rXsDfw

Comment: Great golfing ;)

Comment: [186 bytes](http://tinyurl.com/ya4xmzcd). You can also easily port this to Python 3 in [192 bytes](https://tio.run/##NczBTgIxEIDh@z5FDZrOZJsNlWiAgPoOe1QPXSgwodvWaUvFl1856OE//JcvXvMp@MU00RgDZ8G26bdsu1QGYAkdfuhWKmfGYW/EuE6ZwVkPY3fkUCLMEbH9H42KfCwZEJtDYGHUIMiLH4ogzbDb28PxRHR2LnyllC@X72utN5tSBvm2hOfFbDXTdxtN89XTffuyeXiV2L7LUqSSj0V@4rrf9h3b6MzOwk1XGpvI5DP0OE211vDXLw), but I don't think it should be a separate answer.

Comment: @NieDzejkob It seems as though your golfed Python 2 version produces a different output than the OP's current version or your Python 3 version.

Comment: @JomathanFrech sorry, as always testing on production. [188 bytes](https://tio.run/##NczBTgIxEIDh@z5FDZCZyTYbitEIAfQd9qgmdKHAxG5buy0FX37loIf/8F@@cEtn7xbjyH3wMYloqnYTTTPkDiNgQx@qBml13x206Fc7axz2zSn6HHBOtKv/R5FkF3JCouroo9CyE@zEDwcE3e0P5ng6M39Z67@HIV0u11spd5iHhPD2gs@Pk@VEPawVz5dP03q7nr0C1e@QM0hYZPikVbtpm2iC1XuDd10qqkJkl0Q7jlBK8X/BLw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>103</s> 102 bytes

```
aR:`(.)\1+`#_.B
Fm"abcdefghiiklloqsstvvwwxy"Z"@8(63#9#1!<1i095$+><WU%?"I#Ya@?@maRA:ym@1aR'W"uu"R'U"2u"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/McgqQUNPM8ZQO0E5Xs@Jyy1XKTEpOSU1LT0jMzM7Jye/sLi4pKysvLyiUilKycFCw8xY2VLZUNHGMNPA0lRF284mPFTVXslTOTLRwd4hNzHI0aoy18EwMUg9XKm0VClIPVTJqFTp////BYnFxeX5RSlAIi8ltSitNAcA)

#### Explanation

The code does three steps of transformation:

```
aR:`(.)\1+`#_.B  Process runs of identical letters

a                1st cmdline argument
 R:              Do this replacement and assign back to a:
   `(.)\1+`       This regex (matches 2 or more of same character in a row)
           #_.B   Replace with callback function: concatenate (length of full match) and
                  (first capture group)
                  Note: #_.B is a shortcut form for {#a.b}

Fm"..."Z"..."I#Ya@?@maRA:ym@1  Do the bulk of rules 2-25

  "..."                        String of letters to replace
       Z"..."                  Zip with string of characters to replace with
Fm                             For each m in the zipped list:
                   @m           First item of m is letter to replace
                a@?             Find its index in a, or nil if it isn't in a
               Y                Yank that into y
             I#                 If len of that is truthy:*
                     aRA:        Replace character in a at...
                         y        index y...
                          m@1     with second item of m

aR'W"uu"R'U"2u"  Clean up substitution
                 In the previous step, the replacements each had to be a single character.
                 This doesn't work for uu and 2u, so we use W and U instead (safe, since
                 uppercase letters won't be in the input) and replace them here with the
                 correct substitutions.
aR'W"uu"         In a, replace W with uu
        R'U"2u"  and U with 2u
                 and print the result (implicit)
```

* We need to test whether `a@?m@0` is nil. It's not enough to test that it's truthy, since 0 is a legitimate index that is falsey. Pip doesn't have a short builtin way to test if a value is nil, but testing its length works well enough in this case: any number will have length at least 1 (truthy), and nil has length of nil (falsey).