# RLE Brainfuck dialect

Tags: code-golf, string, brainfuck

## RLE Brainfuck

(related to [BF-RLE](https://esolangs.org/wiki/BF-RLE))

The hypothetical RLE ([Run-Length Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding)) dialect of Brainfuck accepts the symbols for the 8 commands and also accepts digits. The digits are used to represent the number of successive repetitions of a command, thus allowing run-length encoding of the source code.

`8>` is equal to `>>>>>>>>`.

The length is always on the left side of the command.

Your task is to write the shortest program/function that translates the input string (RLE Brainfuck fragment) into a regular Brainfuck program.

For example:

Input:

```
10+[>+>3+>7+>10+4<-]3>2+.>+.7+2.3+.2<2+.>15+.>.3+.6-.8-.2<+.<.
```

Ouptut:

```
++++++++++[>+>+++>+++++++>++++++++++<<<<-]>>>++.>+.+++++++..+++.<<++.>+++++++++++++++.>.+++.------.--------.<<+.<.
```

The shortest code in byte count in each language will win.

Comment: I'm confused. Is the goal to output the fixed string corresponding to translating the given string?

Comment: Is the program given as input, or should we hardcode it?

Comment: *Your task is to write the shortest program/function that translates the following RLE Brainfuck fragment into regular Brainfuck program* - Should our  submissions work for any valid Brainfuck code or just that piece of code? You should also include the desired output by the way.

Comment: Although this is a valid challenge, it received 2 VTC (at the time of writing this comment) as unclear (up to the site's standard). You can try the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) next time.

Comment: Hi, I edited the description. The program should work for any valid RLE BF code and display the translated program.

Comment: Hi, I downvoted this question because I feel that it's going to be dominated by one or two RLE-based regex algorithms that are then just copied to each language's individual regex formatting. There's very little room to golf anything here.

Comment: This looks a lot like a generic [run-length decoding challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/12902/20260). The difference here is that multidigit numbers are supported. I think it's still a dupe, but I won't hammer it.

Comment: @user202729 Thanks, I'll use it next time.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork Hi, Thanks for the feedback. Now I understand that my idea was stupid.

Comment: Hi, I added clarification that the shortest code in each language wins.

Comment: @xnor The other difference is that digits are not always present — this form of RLE guarantees far less structure, and IMO can lead to interesting techniques (compare my Python answer here with the one in the linked challenge!)

Comment: @GalenIvanov Can the input contain things like `0<`?

Comment: @Lynn I haven't explicitly described this, but as is seen in the example, 1 is ommited; adding 0 doesn't make the string shorter, so the answer is no, no zeroes can prepend a command.

Comment: The other direction would be more interesting, I think (i.e. transform a brainfuck programm in the shortest equivalent RLE brainfuck program).

Comment: I [kinda sorta](https://github.com/carcigenicate/ezfuck) implemented this language awhile ago if anyone's interested.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann It'd be *really* difficult to prove that it was the shortest equivalent.  You'd need to recognize that, e.g., `>+++<[>++++<-]` is equivalent to `12+`, but only if the second cell is 0 always 0 when the code is executed, which requires some serious static analysis if it appears inside any looping/branching structures.  And since in the general case, pretty much any interesting static analysis is going to reduce to the halting problem, it may actually be *impossible* to prove optimality. Converting to *an* equivalent RLE-BF program would be possible, though.

Comment: @Ray I meant some "weaker" form of equivalence, basically the one implemented by this challenge (i.e. two RLE brainfuck programs are equivalent if they expand to the same brainfuck program). Finding the shortest (or one of the shortest, as `++` and `+2` have the same length) from such a family should be easily decidable. The general equivalence in the computer science meaning is non-decidable, of course.

Answer (score 24):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>62</s> 61 bytes

```python
lambda s:eval(re.sub('(\d*)(.)',r'+1*\1*1*"\2"',s))
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcjdCoIwGIDh865ieLKfTz/arIyw3UiLmDhJ8GfMWXT1S09eeF7/i@95Uqm7mzTYsWktWW7uYwcWHC5rwygzreAMOc0DBSmMFFJkRmU0Xzg/9KOfQyTBJR/6KZKOBft99ZNfI@M8ySM8NOgSdAV6w6kunqVWgBqwAoUloKp3yvOWnZcCr8U2AWv8Aw)

The regex substitution expands `3<2+-` into the string:

```python
+1*3*1*"<"+1*2*1*"+"+1**1*"-"
```

which is then `eval`ed. (Note how when `\1` is empty, we get `1**1 = 1`.) The first `+` is a unary operator which binds to the first number, and the other `+`s are string concatenation. This beats the more obvious

```python
lambda s:re.sub('(\d+)(.)',lambda m:int(m.group(1))*m.group(2),s)
import re
```

by 14 bytes. Ordinarily `"\2"` wouldn’t always work, but thankfully `\` and `"` aren’t brainfuck commands.

---

**xnor** saved a byte, supplying the `1*\1*1` trick. Previously I had `\1L` in the regex, and defined `L=1` as a lambda argument, which is also pretty cool: `3L` is a long int literal and `L` is a variable.

Comment: That's a slick use of `L` to handle the empty string. There's a shorter way though, `r'+1*\1*1*"\2"'`.

Comment: ...Why is `import re` below the lambda?

Comment: Putting the lambda first means I can use tio.run's Header/Footer feature to show off how the code is supposed to be invoked (I put `f=\ ` in the Header — now the lambda has a name!)

Answer (score 18):

## [Pyth](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=r9&input=%2210%2B%5B%3E%2B%3E3%2B%3E7%2B%3E10%2B4%3C-%5D3%3E2%2B.%3E%2B.7%2B2.3%2B.2%3C2%2B.%3E15%2B.%3E.3%2B.6-.8-.2%3C%2B.%3C.%22&debug=0), 2 bytes

```
r9
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=r9&input=%2210%2B%5B%3E%2B%3E3%2B%3E7%2B%3E10%2B4%3C-%5D3%3E2%2B.%3E%2B.7%2B2.3%2B.2%3C2%2B.%3E15%2B.%3E.3%2B.6-.8-.2%3C%2B.%3C.%22&debug=0)**

### How it works

```
r9  - Full program receiving the String from STDIN.

r   - Pyth's set of extended string operations.
 9  - The ninth command of that set (run-length decode). This supports multi-digit numbers.
```

Comment: Darn, Jelly RLD borks :( :P

Comment: Necessary reminder: **[Stop upvoting trivial solutions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10127/how-can-we-help-users-who-are-put-off-by-the-use-of-golfing-languages/10132#10132)** (like this one).

Comment: It's not so trivial to know about that command, and to know it works when numbers are missing

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Wait, what? Isn't the entire point of code golf to have the lowest byte count?

Comment: @Deacon It is, but trivial answers shouldn't be upvoted too much in my opinion, since they (might) discourage new users that don't know of these golfing languages.

Comment: @Deacon yes, but a golfed Python answer is usually a lot harder to make and more interesting than a 2-byte golflang answer.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder People can certainly upvote if they wish.

Comment: @Stephen Yeah, but this doesn't have a popularity-contest tag, it has a code-golf tag.

Comment: @Deacon Upvoting isn't just about upvoting short solutions. Users are generally encouraged to upvote solutions that are interesting and creative as opposed to trivial short solutions in golfing languages.

Answer (score 17):

### Lua, <s>65</s> <s>64</s> 63 Bytes

<s>Great ! For once, Lua beats Python !</s>

**Edit: Saved one byte thanks to @Jarhmander, thanks to him for the useful trick to force a single result**

```lua
print(((...):gsub("(%d+)(.)",function(a,b)return b:rep(a)end)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FchBCsIwEEDRq0hBmGGawSZqSwlzEXGR2CgFiSUm50/TzYf3v8XVuqU1ZgBgZpw//@Khg/NCCIxd/y7xlddfBNd7TCGXFE9@TmEDhyEuiFhrHS70EBJDMpI0XK16GtHEQjySZkOs7cHh1nLwrnhSbRJb3gE)

#### Explanations

```lua
print)((...):gsub(             -- iterate over the argument and replace the strings
            "(%d+)(.)",       -- matching this pattern (at least one digit and a non-digit)
            function(a,b)     -- capture the digit and non-digit parts in separate variables
              return b:rep(a) -- repeat the non-digit a times, a being the digit part
            end)))
```

Comment: [Beat you! :)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146928/3852)

Comment: @Lynn One byte down, 3 more to go!

Comment: You can save a byte by removing `,""` and enclosing in parens the entire print argument. Expressions enclosed in parens are adjusted to one value in Lua (see https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4).

Answer (score 11):

## [Scala](https://scala-lang.org), <s>73</s> 69 bytes

```scala
"(\\d+)(.)".r.replaceSomeIn(_:String,m=>Some("$2"*m.group(1).toInt))
```

[Try it online!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/WrkFSl0qSHa5imoQJIHLBg)

Comment: This is a nice answer! Welcome to the site. :)

Answer (score 10):

### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 18 bytes

**17 bytes code + 1 for `-p`.**

```perl
s/\d+(.)/$1x$&/ge
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fcg7CoAwEEXRzYgoj0xM4q8IsxG1U0QQDcbC1TvG5sK5Ybn2RiTqcUZBpc7Mk@V6XURMhYHBDtyBE2qvJscWxKAOlhzI@p@mSfnZKupVmiBP7xnu7TyiqPAB)

Answer (score 9):

## RLE Brainfuck, 204 bytes

```
-3>,[[->+>+<<]>>47-3<10+<->[-<+4>->+<[>-]>[3<+<[-]4>->]5<]3>57+[-]+<<[>>-<<[3>+3<-]]3>[3<+3>-]<[>>+7<+[->11-<+[-<+]->>+[-<[->10+<]>>+]<[-4>.4<]4>[-]-3<-<+7>-7<[8>+8<-]]8>[8<+8>-]<[3<.3<[-]-6>-]7<--5>-]<,]
```

As I understand it the specs for the brainfuck environment aren't super well-defined. This program assumes that the cells in the tape allow arbitrarily large positive and negative integers, with no overflow. This code will transcribe non-command comments as well, but it will expand the run-length encoding of comments (eg "see 3b" → "see bbb"). The resulting program should run the same, so I'm not too concerned.

I'm pretty sure I could still golf a few bytes off this but I'm exhausted from working with it.

[Here's](https://eval.in/893142) the custom interpreter + tests I've been using to test it. If you pass it input in the Standard Input box it should run against that input instead of running the tests.

My messy ungolfed workpad:

```
->>>,
[
  [->+>+<<]>>  clone 2 into 3 and 4
  if read char is between zero and nine
  (num buffer | max | is_digit | original char | read | temp0 | temp1)
                                                   ^
  47-
  <<<10+  set max
  <->  handle gross 0 case
  [  while max
    -  max minus one
    <+  buffer plus one
    >>>>-  read minus one
    IF STATEMENT : if read is 0
    >+<
    [>-]>[<
      <<+  is_digit = 1
      <[-]>>>  max = 0
    >->]<<  back to read
    <<<     back to max
  ]

  >>>57+[-]  reset `read` (need to add first to avoid infinite negative)

  +<<  check is_digit flag
  ( end marker | 0 | is_digit | original char | temp0 | temp1 | temp2 | temp3)
  x[  IF READ WAS DIGIT
    CODE 1a
    >>temp0 -<<x
    [>>>temp1 +<<<x-]
  ]
  >>>temp1 [<<<x+>>>temp1 -]
  <temp0 [
    START CODE 2a
    >>temp2 +
    7<y+[  IF THERE IS A NUMBER PREFIX
      -
      START CODE 1b
      >11-  end marker is negativeone
      <   on smallest digit
      +[-<+]->  find largest digit
      >+[  sum digits until we hit the end marker negativeone
        -
        <[->10+<]>  h1 = ten * h0; h0 = 0
        >
        +
      ]  leave the negativeone at zero though
      num | 0 | 0 | 0 | original char
            ^
      <num
      [->>>>.<<<<]  print `original char` `num` times
      >>>>[-]-  set `char` to negativeone
      <<<- last ditch guess
      END CODE 1b
      <y+
      7>temp2 -
      7<y[8>temp3 +8<y-]
    ]
    8>temp3 [8<y+8>temp3 -]
    <temp2 [
      CODE 2b
      <<<.  print original char
      <<<[-]-  set num buffer to new left edge
      >>>>>>temp2 -
    ]
    7<y--

    END CODE 2a
    5>temp0 -
  ]
  <
  ,
]
```

Comment: Does the gross 0 case only refer to actual zero counts, or does it also happen when parsing, e.g. `10+`?  The OP clarified in a comment that count will always be greater than 0, so you might be able to shave some bytes off if it's the former.

Comment: Gross 0 case is for parsing any 0. Since the `while max` loop always runs at least once, and I'm unconditionally upping the buffer where I store the digit's value in that loop, I need to start that buffer at -1. I wonder if I could save some bytes by leaving that buffer logically at `value+1` though 

Answer (score 8):

## vim, <strike>29</strike> <strike>25</strike> <strike>23</strike> <strike>22</strike> 16 bytes

```
:s/\D/a&<C-v><ESC>/g
D@"
```

`<C-V>` is 0x16, `<ESC>` is 0x1b.

It works by replacing each non-digit with a command that appends that character to the buffer.  The counts are left alone and modify those commands.  At this point, the buffer is a vimscript program that produces the desired Brainfuck program, so we pull it into a register and run it.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/36pYP0YjxiVGUz8xxlBMWj@dKyXFQen/f0MD7Wg7bTtjbTtzbTsgx8RGN9bYzkhbz05bz1zbSM9YW8/IBsQ1NAUSIK6Zrp6FLlBQW89GDwA)

Edit: Size reductions thanks to suggestions: H.PWiz: 5, TheFamilyFroot: 5, DJMcMayhem: 1

Comment: [*TheFamilyFroot*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/45000) had a nice golfing tip: you don't need to use a capturing group, you can just use group 0 (`&` or `\0`) instead with no parentheses. Also, a tip from me, not *TheFamilyFroot* is that you could use `D` instead of `dd` for `-1` byte.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions, H.PWiz, TheFamilyFroot, and DJMcMayhem.  That brought it below the 18 byte Perl solution and into second place.  Now we just need to find another 15 bytes we can get rid of and it'll beat the Pyth builtin. :-)

Answer (score 6):

## [Stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), 24 bytes

```
['(\d+)(.)'[\#~*]3/repl]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JTM5OTfn/P1pdIyZFW1NDT1M9Oka5TivWWL8otSAn9r@DVRoXl7qhgXa0nbadsbadubYdkGNioxtrbGekrWenrWeubaRnrK1nZAPiGpoCCRDXTFfPQhcoqK1no6eukKaQX1ryHwA)

### Explanation

```
['(\d+)(.)'[\#~*]3/repl]
[                      ]   anonymous function, taking string as argument
 '(\d+)(.)'                for all matches of this regex:
           [    ]3/repl      replace (stack = (whole match, digit, repetend))
            \#~              convert digit to number
               *             repeat the character by that digit
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>28</s> 23 bytes

*thanks to @Leo for -5 bytes*

```
\d+
$*
+`1(1\D)
$1$1
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcgxDoAgEAXRfs9Bof6wcUHFgmzlLcREEy1sLIz3R2gmefNe3/0cOacTZDrCLo2kpSUjRkgoZ@mxKtRDA7RgiHbz6sAKDnDswS5WylhSOVmebZngyD8)

Comment: Can you use `\b` in the second regex to only match one `1` per run of `1`s?

Comment: Or you could do something like [this](https://tio.run/##FcgxDoAgEAXRfs9Bof6wcUHFgmzlLcREEy1sLIz3R2gmefNe3/0cOacTZDrCLo2kpSUjRkgoZ@mxKtRDA7RgiHbz6sAKDnDswS5WylhSOVmebZngyD8 "Retina – Try It Online")

Answer (score 5):

## TeX, 124 bytes

```
\newcount\n\def\b{\afterassignment\r\n0}\def\r#1{\ifx;#1\else\p#1\expandafter\b\fi
}\def\p#1{#1\ifnum\n>1\advance\n-1\p#1\fi}
```

(wrote in two lines to be visible, but the code can be written in one line)

This defines a macro `\b` that takes the input in the form `\b<input>;`, and prints the output wanted to the document.

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyon](https://github.com/alexander-liao/pyon), 66 bytes

```
print(re.sub("\d+.",lambda k:(int(k.group()[:-1])*k.group()[-1]),a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6jMz/v/v6AoM69EoyhVr7g0SUMpJkVbT0knJzE3KSVRIdtKAySXrZdelF9aoKEZbaVrGKupheCDuDqJ//8bGmhH21lo2@jG2ukBAA)

Pyon is pretty much just Python, but this is shorter because `re` is automatically imported when you use it, and `a` is automatically set to an argument or the input

-4 bytes thanks to Mr. Xcoder

Comment: You should change `g[0]` to `g[:-1]` (fails for the given test case or any number higher than 9).

Comment: Anyway why would you even need a `lambda` which actually wastes bytes? Golfed and corrected for [66 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6jMz/v/v6AoM69EoyhVr7g0SUMpJkVbT0knJzE3KSVRIdtKAySXrZdelF9aoKEZbaVrGKupheCDuDqJ//8bGmhH21lo2@jG2ukBAA)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder whoops, not sure what I was thinking... thanks

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder oh yeah I try to golf things a lot that end up being ungolfs xD

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>100</s> <s>93</s> 89 bytes

-7 with thanks to Mr.Xcoder

```python
n=b=""
for y in input():
 if"/"<y<":":n+=y
 elif""==n:b+=y
 else:b+=y*int(n);n=""
print b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcxBCsIwEAXQfU8RZtU6dLSJWonJXETcFFoMlGmodZHTx1SE4fPfX0xM22sRnbP4wQNU07KqpIKUi5@tbmylwgRHcMmBBSvoU6XGuWzgvdjh7/f4q4cgWy3NXfZXcS1SQ87QnfDByAa5Ry44u/ZpWCMxUo@aDJJ2O7tLiZ3Xlm5tGZEcwRc)

Comment: A few golfs for [93 bytes](https://tio.run/##LczBDsIgEATQO19B9tS66WpBrUHgR4wXkjaSNFtS64GvR2q8TObNYVLeXgurUqKLnD5b0wp2wQGIaVlllpFlNELGCY5gswUDhtFlIce5buAcm/D3e/zVQ@St4fbO@0laq2QoBfoTPjx6jX5AX3G23VN7heSRBlSkkZTd2V9q7Lx2dOvqiGQJvg). It can be golfed further though.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 60 bytes

```hs
f(a:b)|[(c,d:e)]<-reads$a:b=(<$)d[1..c]++f e|1<2=a:f b
f a=a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcixDoMgEIDhvU9xg4PmyqVAWxsCvIhxOBFSo3VQR9@d4vIn3//lfY7LknOq2QzN2dXhPprY9FZskce9KtfVtmrGThKFHjFBPKVVjk2C4ZaAHecfTys4mNYjbhwOSFk@sPPoNfoWfcHTil57heSRWlSkkZS9KF8lF9@CPqJMJEt/)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>121</s> <s>106</s> 90 bytes

```r
function(s,a=strsplit)cat(rep(el(a(gsub("\\d","",s),"")),pmax(el(a(s,"\\D")),"1")),sep="")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzNDoIwEITvPkZP22zZCKh4gJ58C/FQsCgJP023JPr02MbLl3wzk/H7NHbe@C/MNrzXJ8vD0OzDtvRhXBdgZRoOnt00BtmbAN46sBMYePHWgWjbp1BCKJaRUio3m8@/ZxXLW8pEnsjWNXGyDyDyI9416hJ1hTrKqc4epS6QNFKFBZVIRZ00P0ckvWR0zWKIVFP8@AE)

Saved 15 bytes by realising that `rep()` will coerce to numeric.
Saved another 16 thanks to Giuseppe, mainly from the use of `pmax` to replace empty strings with `1`

```r
function(s) {
  x <- el(strsplit(s,"\\D")) # Split the string on anything that is not a digit...
  x <- pmax(x, "1")          # ... and replace any empty strings with 1. This gets us the numbers of repeats
  y <- gsub("\\d","",s)      # Remove all digits from the original string...
  y <- el(strsplit(y))       # ... and split into individual units. This gets us the symbols to repeat
  z <- rep(y, x)             # Implement the repeats. x is coerced to numeric
  cat(z, sep = "")           # Print without separators
}
```

Comment: very nice! I believe `ifelse(x>"",x,1)` is a byte shorter, and `\\D` is equivalent to `[^\\d]` _and_ best of all, you don't need `perl=T`, so this is a sweet [99 bytes](https://tio.run/##HYzBDoIwEAXvfkZP22xpBFQ80J78C/FQsNUmFUhbEvx6XLy8ZGaSF7fg@2jiFz42v6dn4genNreMQ/bTCEkYlXJMc/BZrMoGMORY190Y53wwGaKd4a9faemBypMJxkTitJwL72xIFlZNbhUlmWRnRWlzwMoj3jXqGnWDmuDUFo9aVyg1ygYrWaOs2h3LM82Ol0JeC5IoW0kfPw "R – Try It Online"). I really didn't think this could be fewer than 100 bytes!

Comment: [90 bytes with `pmax`](https://tio.run/##JYzNDoIwEITvPkZP22zZCKh4gJ58C/FQsCgJP023JPr02MbLl3wzk/H7NHbe@C/MNrzXJ8vD0OzDtvRhXBdgZRoOnt00BtmbAN46sBMYePHWgWjbp1BCKJaRUio3m8@/ZxXLW8pEnsjWNXGyDyDyI9416hJ1hTrKqc4epS6QNFKFBZVIRZ00P0ckvWR0zWKIVFP8@AE "R – Try It Online")

Comment: @Giuseppe Very clever use of `pmax` giving a nice big improvement - thanks!

Comment: replace `"1"` with `1` as `pmax` will coerce to `character` for the comparison.

Comment: [85 bytes](https://tio.run/##FYxLDoIwFAD33oK3avNKI6DignblLcSkfIqS8Gn6SqKnx7KZZGYxfp/G1jf@x2YbPmtP/DSofdiWLozrwkgYNIqCJzeNQZjEKDvxrgnMW8eSN20tg7ruQQAI4hjp5ubLEsKYHyAyzgVZpwD4PjDIzvjUqAvUJeoolyp9FTpHqVGWmMsCZV4dml0jDr2l8p7GiLKS8fEH) by changing the aliases

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>66</s> 62 bytes

```powershell
-join("$args"-split'\b'|%{(,$(,$_[0]*$n+$_))[!!($n=$($_-1))]})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcjhCsIgFIbha9k4oXbysM1q/TBvxEQKRi3EjRn0o7p2c/DxwvPN03tY0mMIIWf5nMbIa7gu91TLNIfxxS439t18@A7KvG3cFiKCF8JWFYd4Bg5etkK4n8g5s7ZBa9AoND2agr2WTpkOySD12JFC6vTK9lCy8ijpJMuJpIn9AQ)

## Breakdown

What a mess!

Starting from `$args`, which is a single element array containing the RLE string, I'm forcing into an actual string by wrapping it quotes.

Then split it by word boundary (`\b` in regex). That will give me an array of strings, where each element is either a number or the BF token(s) that come after the number. So in the example, the first 4 elements of this split array are `10`,`+]>+>`,`3`,`+>` (all are string).

Next, I pipe that into `ForEach-Object` (`%`) to deal with each *element*.

The middle is a well-known PowerShell golfism, with a twist; it's essentially a DIY ternary operator, in which you create a 2 element array then index into it using the boolean expression you want to test, whereby a false result gives you element 0 and a true result gives you element 1.

In this case, I actually create a single element array with the unary comma `,` operator, because I don't want output in the true case.

First let's look at the indexer, even though it gets executed later.

The idea of this is that `$_` (the current element) could either be a valid number, or some other string. If it's a number, I want `$n` to be the value of that number minus 1 (as a number, not a string). If it's not, I want `$n` to be false-y.

PowerShell usually tries to coerce the right-hand value to the type of the left side, but it can depend on the operation. For addition, `"10"+5` would give you a new string, `"105"`, whereas `10+"5"` will give you an integer (`15`).

But strings can't be subtracted so instead PowerShell can infer the numeric value automatically with a string on the left side of subtraction, therefore `"10"-5` gives `5`.

SO, I start with `$_-1`, which will give me the number I want when `$_` is actually a number, but when it's not I get nothing. On the surface, "nothing" is falsey, but the problem is that is stops execution of that assignment, so `$n` will retain its previous value; not what I want!

If I wrap it in a subexpression, then when it fails, I get my falsey value: `$($_-1)`.

That all gets assigned to `$n` and since that assignment is itself wrapped in parentheses, the value that was assigned to `$n` also gets passed through to the pipeline.

Since I'm using it in the indexer, and I want `1` if the conversion succeeded, I use two boolean-`not` expressions `!!` to convert this value to boolean. A successful number conversion ends up as true, while the falsey nothingness gives us that sweet, sweet `0` that allows for returning the only element in that fake ternary array.

Getting back to that array, the element is this: <s>`$("$($_[0])"*$n*$_)`</s> `$(,$_[0]*$n+$_)`

<s>`"$($_[0])"` - this is an annoyingly long way of getting the first character of the current element (let's say, getting `+` from `+[>+`), but as a string and not as a `[char]` object. I need it to be a string because I can multiply a string by a number to duplicate it, but I can't do that with a character.</s>

Actually I managed to save 4 characters by using a `[char]` array instead of a string (by using another unary comma `,`), so I was able to remove the quotes and extra sub-expression. I *can* multiply an array to duplicate its elements. And since the entire result of this iteration ends up being an array anyway and needs to be `-join`ed, using an array here incurs no additional cost.

Then, I multiply that <s>string</s> array by `$n`, to duplicate it `$n` times. Recall that `$n` could be `$null` or it could be the value of the preceding digits minus one.

Then `+$_` adds the current element onto the end of the duplicated first character of that element. That's why `$n` is minus one.

This way, `10+[>+` ends up with `$n` equal to 9, then we make 9 `+`'s and add that back to the `+[>+` string to get the requisite 10, plus the other single elements along for the ride.

The element is wrapped in a subexpression `$()` because when `$n` is `$null`, the entire expression fails, so creating the array fails, so the indexer never runs, so `$n` never gets assigned.

The reason I used this ternary trick is because of one of its peculiarities: unlike a real ternary operator, the expressions that define the elements *do* get evaluated whether or not they are "selected", and first for that matter.

Since I need to assign and then use `$n` on separate iterations, this is helpful. The ternary array element value gets evaluated with the previous iteration's `$n` value, then the indexer re-assigns `$n` for the current iteration.

So the `ForEach-Object` loops ends up outputting everything its supposed to (a bunch of errors we ignore), but as an array of new strings.

So that whole thing is wrapped in parentheses and then preceded by unary `-join` to give the output string.

Comment: Great explanation, that alone warrants an upvote already.

Comment: Thanks @Mast, and because of your comment I looked over my answer again and realized how I could save 4 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [QuadR](https://github.com/abrudz/QuadRS), 17 bytes

```apl
\d+.
¯1((⍎↓)⍴↑)⍵M
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyxNTCn6/z8mRVuP69B6Qw2NR719j9omaz7q3fKobSKQ2ur7/7@hgXa0nbadsbadubYdkGNioxtrbGekrWenrWeubaRnrK1nZAPiGpoCCRDXTFfPQhcoqK1nowcA)

Thanks to [Adám](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/3073/ad%C3%A1m) for providing the correct version of the code.

#### How it works:

```apl
\d+.          ⍝ Regex to match any sequence of digits followed by a character.
¯1((⍎↓)⍴↑)⍵M  ⍝ Transformation line
¯1(      )⍵M  ⍝ Arguments: -1 and the matching expression
   ( ↓)       ⍝ 'Drop' the last item (-1) from the match (⍵M), yielding a string which is a sequence of digits.
    ⍎         ⍝ Execute. In this case, it transforms a string into a number.
        ↑     ⍝ 'Take' the last item (-1) from the match (⍵M), yielding a character.
       ⍴      ⍝ Reshape it. That will take the character resulting from the 'Take' operation and repeat it n times,
              ⍝ where n is the result from the 'Drop' and 'Execute' operations.
```

Comment: Equivalent to the APL function [`'\d+.'⎕R{¯1((⍎↓)⍴↑)⍵.Match}`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wT1mBRtPfVHfVODqg@tN9TQeNTb96htsuaj3i2P2iYCqa16voklyRm1QNXqhgba0XbadsbadubadkCOiY1urLGdkbaenbaeubaRnrG2npENiGtoCiRAXDNdPQtdoKC2no2eOgA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 50 bytes

```
x=>/\d+./.sub(k=>int((e=k.group())[to-1])*e[-1],x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKL8nP@59m@7/C1k4/JkVbT1@vuDRJI9vWLjOvREMj1TZbL70ov7RAQ1MzuiRf1zBWUys1GkjpVGj@LygCqUnTUDLTjraz0LbRjbXTU9LU/A8A)

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 148 bytes

```java
s->{for(s=s.format(s.replaceAll("(\\d+)","%1\\$0$1d"),0);!s.matches("\\D+");s=s.replaceAll("0(\\D)","$1$1"));return s.replaceAll("((.)+)\\2","$1");}
```

<sup><sup><sup><s>*Gdamn*</s></sup></sup></sup> Java regexes are so useless sometimes.. Last time it was [lack of using the capture group `"$1"` for anything](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145775/52210), now this.. I want to replace `3c` with `ccc` or `000c` with `ccc` as a one-liner, but unfortunately Java has no way of doing this without a loop. Ah well.

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##fU9BasMwELznFVvhgoTixXbaJuBEUMi1ufQY5aDaSuvUkY2lBErw29118aH0UBArzWpmdvZkriZuWutO5edQ1MZ7eDGVu80AKhdsdzSFhd0IAV5DV7l3KPj08CKnfj@j4oMJVQE7cLCBwcfqdmw67jce6T6bwD12tq3J7LmuOeNal1KwObtPtY6SKC2ZmCciv/NI5OLDes603kom8tHjtzQh7XaURmmUMiHyzoZL5@DPAI5CCq2zHyLZ9MOYlU57easp6RT42lQlnGnhaaf9AYyYtv3ywZ6xuQRs6SvUjjssOFupceq/lDSReyXVQqqlVAQe1vFhoTKJSuJSZriQmK1HmD5SGeFTjKuYmhLXONn3s374Bg)

```java
s->{                          // Method with String as both parameter and return-type
  for(s=s.format(s.replaceAll("(\\d+)","%1\\$0$1d"),0);
                              //  Replace every numbers of that many zeroes
                              //  (i.e. "3>2+" -> "000>00+")
      !s.matches("\\D+");     //  Loop as long as the String contains zeroes
    s=s.replaceAll("0(\\D)",  //   Replace every 0 followed by a non-0 character,
                   "$1$1")    //   with two times this captured non-0 character
  );                          //  End of loop
  return s.replaceAll("((.)+)\\2","$1");
                              //  Reduce every repeated character amount by 1,
                              //  and return this as result
}                             // End of method
```

Comment: Hi Kevin, good to see you here, dealing with puzzles other than twisty :)

Comment: @GalenIvanov Oh, hi! I had no idea you were active on PPCG as well.

Comment: I wasn't until recently :) I'm learning J and decided that this is a good opportunity to test my skills.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 151 bytes

[Outgolfed by user2390246](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/146911/rle-brainfuck-dialect/146962#146962)! This is now basically a garbage approach compared to that one, but I'll continue to improve it.

```r
function(s,G=substr)for(i in el(strsplit(gsub("(\\d+.)","!\\1!",s),"!")))cat("if"(is.na(g<-as.double(G(i,1,(n=nchar(i))-1))),i,rep(G(i,n,n),g)),sep='')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYyxbsQgEET7fIWP5nYFrIKd5FJg2vuIOAW2wYfkYAtwka93uDSjeTOaSecaxmTTL/y48tjmjC@@0bI5/RGnErYIWdz7fIy5JPRbgtCE2LgVKud9DQWWWgKDYZg5IRPsMgzqwkTGahkiTrYAC55ByBQtLFraTPN2jKuDOwShBMQ@Tg9bvxGlqhMRRHL7fxtFRLHUKLu9v17x9MDUK/8y3HTc3Lip8Kbld2daTobTjbfUcWr1E9V7lSd@SPqUNeSkieH5Bw)

Also outputs a bunch of warnings.

```r
function(s){
s <- gsub("(\\d+.)","!\\1!",s)               # surround groups with !
X <- el(strsplit(s,"!"))                   # split to groups
for( i in X ){                             # iterate over groups
 n <- nchar(i)                             # length of group
 r <- substr(i,1,n-1)                      # potential number (first n-1 chars)
 d <- substr(i,n,n)                        # last character
 if( is.na(as.double(r)) ){                # if it's not a number
   cat(i)                                  # print out the whole string
  } else {
   cat(rep(d,as.double(r)),sep="")         # repeat d r times, and print with no separator
  }
 }
}
```

Next up, seeing if using a `grep` is more efficient than `substr`

Comment: [A different approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146962/66252)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 84 bytes

```hs
f s@(x:r)|(n:m,x:r)<-span(`elem`['0'..'9'])s=(x<$[1..read$n:m])++f r|1<3=x:f r
f e=e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYrRCoMgGEbv9xReBBr//Mnc1hYqe48Ikk1ZrGRYF1307s5uPs45fB@7fN00peTJ8mRbG8udhXY@H6T48rOBDW5y89DRiiLSB@3LRbNNFZ1AjM6@i3zvSwBP4i6U1Fub6eSJ0y7NdgxEkzGsLtrXSnwSFXQGjATTgMlyUbyXpgY0gA3UKAFrdai45jn0xvHOcwRU@Ac)

**Explanation:**

`` span(`elem`['0'..'9'])s `` splits the given string `s` into a prefix of digits and the remainder. Matching on the result on the pattern `(n:m,x:r)` ensures that the digit prefix is non-empty and binds the character after the digits to `x` and the remainder to `r`. `x<$[1..read$n:m]` reads the string of digits `n:m` as number and repeats `x` that many times. The result is concatenated to the recursive treatment of the remaining string `r`.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 46 bytes

```
a=>a.replace(/(\d+)(.)/g,(_,n,b)=>b.repeat(n))
```

Pretty straightforward explanation:

```
a=>a.replace(/(\d+)(.)/g,                      // Match globally the following: a number N followed by a character
                         (_,n,b)=>b.repeat(n)) // Replace each occurrence by the matched character repeated N times
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 35 bytes

```ruby
->s{s.gsub(/(\d+)(.)/){$2*$1.to_i}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcjRCoIwGIbhW/FAcOtjn22r7GD9N2ISSBAdJc2BIV77micvPO83jb@83LKRuEa@YhpVq@5PaEXd6rV2h9py/jze25arKc2xWvrGHtELxEM6SMEpmMGLAwXs4OhBF3bac8nOi@HVlAkGNkP@Aw)

Answer (score 1):

### C++, <s>239</s> 235 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to Zacharý

```cpp
#include<regex>
using s=std::string;std::regex m("[0-9]*[<>+.,\\[\\]-]");s t(s r){s d,h;std::sregex_iterator i(r.begin(),r.end(),m),e;while(i!=e){h=(*i)[0];int g=std::strtol(h.data(),NULL,10);g+=!g;d+=s(g,h[h.size()-1]);++i;}return d;}
```

Comment: Can you change `g=(g?g:1)` to `g+=!g`? If that doesn't work, can't you remove the parentheses around `g?g:1`

Comment: [208 bytes](https://tio.run/##PU/LbsQgDLz3K9j0AuuAkk3bbRfCjxBUZRNKOOQhIFKlar89JanUi@0Z22NPtyzUdt327MZl9lG4OURv2lH@M95Y8y2f1uAmi0IdYn@7pZmE@FEffTTiTBX0Q5@VkMDyplFNo6nOCHdTRGkURRyQJz8B9fnAv2aP/5SO9U8XjW/j7JHDd2PdhD3JzdTvaUwVd6fa8B7qgC3UJ3v0BqJoqQkZanx2AEQVOrd1UnF4YH0bW0wI9yaufkI9f2xjm3TTA/vZbl6jEBFnZQFKgqxAXkEm8CKoruQFWHJxhQurgF3EDsvXFHb4Rtk7TSQwwZK9x/YL "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

### [Untyped Lambda Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus), 452 bytes

```
(λp.λq.(λb.λg.(λi.(λp.λq.λb.p q b)(q(λq.λj.λl.j((λq.λj.qλq.λl.(λu.g i j(λp.u)(g j(λq.λg.q(b(p(λp.λq.p q))(p(λp.λq.p(p q)))q g))(λp.u)(λu.u qλq.λu.g j i q(b l(p(λp.λq.p(p(p(p q)))))q u))))λp.p(λp.λb.q p((λp.λq.l(λp.l)(λp.λq.p q)(λq.p j q)q)p b))λp.λp.p)l q))(λp.p)(λp.p(λp.λp.p)λp.λp.p)(λp.λq.p)))(b(p(λp.λp.p))(p(λp.λq.p(p q)))))(λp.λq.λb.p(q b))λp.λq.q(λp.λq.λb.p(λp.λb.b(p q))(λp.b)λp.p)p)λp.λq.λb.q(q(q(q(q(q(p q b))))))
```

Input and output comprise of [right-fold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29#Folds_on_lists) lists of [church encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding) character codes, for example the character code of a newline is 10 so the church encoding would be `λf.λx.f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f x)))))))))`. Converting "ABCD" to a list looks like `λf.λx.f 65 (f 66 (f 67 (f 68 x)))` but with the numbers church-encoded.

Applying an encoded string to the program and reducing it all the way should give you an encoded output string with the RLE applied.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! This looks like an interesting solution but we do expect languages to have a valid interpreter, do you have one of Untyped Lambda Calculus?

Comment: Also, what does the `qλq` notation mean? I've never seen that before.

Answer (score 1):

## [Funky](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Funky), 42 bytes

```
s=>s::gsub("(\\d+)(.)",(_,a,b)=>b::rep(a))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcxBCsIwEIXhu2Q1wySDTdRKSOYibZEGjYhQSmMXnj6mmwffW/x5Xz6/mmMtUYr3r7InUDCOD0JgVBruetYJoyTvt@cKM2Jdt/fyhQyqO9EgJI6kJ2k4BzM5scRC3JNlR2zDwe7S5uDV8M20kziwaqk/)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 24 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
▒tP☻↕╘`¼½ª√ΘBöQm>\%▒IïR}
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=b174500212d460acaba6fbe94294516d3e5c25b1498b527d&i=10%2B%5B%3E%2B%3E3%2B%3E7%2B%3E10%2B4%3C-%5D3%3E2%2B.%3E%2B.7%2B2.3%2B.2%3C2%2B.%3E15%2B.%3E.3%2B.6-.8-.2%3C%2B.%3C.)

Regex replace and execute.

Answer (score 1):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 114 bytes

```
/a/*l//b/l*//l/\/\///1/0a2/1a3/2a4/3a5/4a6/5a7/6a8/7a9/8a*0/9a0*/|l0l/|l/*>/>>b</<<b+/++b-/--b[/[[b]/]]b,/,,b./../
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY07CsMwEAX7HEWyNPLfBuOLKCp2IZBCndvc3dGahTfNm7dXlev7ue4bwVVQqoPKux30JBnoZWSQiVFmJlmYZWWRjVV2NnGJXZLjV1NtgTs5Tz04DvV4r4EQNJOzFkrRjq7TSIy0n0@XF87qRjOMJhnNM5pqNNv4DPwB)

This is fairly trivial program as far as actual algorithm, it just happens that repeating characters is a strong suit of ///.

If you change the specification of the RLE, then its 106 bytes.

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 106 bytes

```
/b/l*//a/*l//l/\/\///1/0a2/1a3/2a4/3a5/4a6/5a7/6a8/7a9/8a*0/9a0l/*>/>>b</<<b+/++b-/--b[/[[b]/]]b,/,,b./../
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYjBCoQwDAX/p7F5tmq1EPIj3R4SWNhDb/4/XWVgYOYedv@@95xwjAAYwgAGPg9AwmoZyTZk27HZgd0KDjtR7MJpFZeFFdXWgaBQdYGIE4g8IkZvaM07evcFy@IMZsxKTUkzaSGttEnsWROxEhdizsQi9GTaH715RD7jO1l4/gE)

A 0 will never occur, and a 1 just adds a byte. 2 is the first number where anything is actually compressed, so it makes much more sense to start at that number. In other words, subtract 1 from each number. This is was the original program, just without the code to subtract one. It takes up so much space because there is an indeterminate amount of zeros at the beginning of each number, depending on the number of digits. If I just used `/0*//` to delete a zero and subtract one, it would delete one for each 0 instead. So it has to add another symbol like this `/0*/|/`, then remove that symbol `/|//`, then remove the `0`s `/0//`.

[Commented version](https://tio.run/##JZDRboMwDEXf9xV@m0QgbmlLi4TyI4iHAO6KRpKJhG18PbOZFOXIju174zjb@KK47/iGiNAUkF5ThJFmShTBzjPMk6cn0RghBn4lGMLIl/XQEzzD4mxKNHLZJx3NOVg//o/hY7ncOfIJWeGMp4xVjrch@G9aUoTnEhwLDpOzM6QAq7fLpkHs2DUFHj8N7GODMbCjo5eriJs38KvraQGbIPiBcvh5TcNLZP00kBbJEs8Z44Kl4IoXwQ2vggpvgjtWggfeBTU@BNkJa@GJh3Bk0BjJNtg0QoVKscFx/ZrZXSLonxA314dZLLIfuxB4@k3iNXvn79o1Tv5DFugkx7tb6IusrO5ocNZvkCZHUWxnBRaFsMW2FXbYdcIc81yoUWvca9UaZUplKmVqdWmKrjRnpY3SldK6VLppFIfnK18S3gp9LySpG73/AQ)

Answer (score 0):

### Dart, 78 bytes (with regex), 102 bytes (without regex)

With Regex:

```
(i)=>i.splitMapJoin(new RegExp(r"(\d+)(.)"),onMatch:(m)=>m[2]*int.parse(m[1]))
```

Without Regex:

```
(i,[n=0,d=0])=>i.codeUnits.map((c)=>i[d++]*((c-=48)>=0&&c<10?0*(n=n*10+c):n<1?1:(n=0*(c=n))+c)).join()
```

Both must be invoked like `(<code here>)("input string")`.

Regex one is quite standard, but the regex-less one is quite special.

Regex-less abuses optional parameters to allocate local variables in "single return" function, otherwise you'd need to make a block and have the return keyword. For each code unit, if the code unit is between 0 and 9 it is accumulated to `n` and an empty string is returned. Otherwise, the the character is multiplied by the value of `n` (special cased if n == 0, in that case it will always emit 1 character) and `n` is set to 0. `(n=0*(c=n))+c` sets the char code argument to the value of `n`, multiplies `n`/`c` with 0, stores 0 to `n`, then adds `c`. This resets our `n` without being in a statement context.

Answer (score 0):

## Python3, 96 bytes

```python
s,r=input(),""
while s:
 d=0
 while"/"<s[d]<":":d+=1
 r+=int(s[:d] or 1)*s[d];s=s[d+1:]
print(r)
```

I tried another implementation in Python, but i don't beat https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146923/56846 :(